# How to specify the base_url with SSL installed?

Tags: codeigniter, ssl

I am using codeigniter to develop an application, everything is fine but I have stacked on how to specify the base_url in `config.php`, I have installed SSL, I need whatever visitor will type the link the ssl should work like this `https://www.zoepoint.com`, but what it do now is user should type the whole link as it is for SSL to work, i.e when you type `www.zoepoint.com`, it comes with no SSL, but also when you type the whole link `https://www.zoepoint.com` or `https://zoepoint.com` it works fine but other links on the website does not work.

Currently I have specified `base_url = 'https://zoepoint.com/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Apache is your web server then add the code below to your `.htaccess` file. This code will force any request to use the `https` protocol.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you @DFriend finally solved with your solution, you have saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$base  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $base;
```

hope this will work for you

Comment: Thank you @Lakru roshan for quick reply, what should I specify on  `SCRIPT_NAME`? is my url name? or I leave as it is!

Comment: @Roman $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] is super global variable so you leave as it is

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
$base_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $base_url;
```